# JSON Decode Parameter Issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, postgresql

I have a rails 4 application that uses `postgresql`. I also have a `backbone.js` application that pushes **JSON** to the rails 4 app.

Here's my controller:

```
def create
 @product = Product.new(ActiveSupport::JSON.decode product_params)

 respond_to do |format|
  if @product.save
    format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @product }
  else
    format.json { render json: @product.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
 end
end
def product_params
  params.require(:product).permit(:title, :data)
end
```

I'm trying to parse the **JSON** and insert the product, but on insert, I'm getting the error:

`TypeError (no implicit conversion of ActionController::Parameters into String):`

Thanks for all help!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your mileage may vary, but I fixed a smilar problem by a bandaid code like this:

```
hash = product_params
hash = JSON.parse(hash) if hash.is_a?(String)
@product = Product.new(hash)
```

The particular problem I had was that if I was just doing `JSON.parse` on the params that contained the object I wanted to create, I was getting this error while unit testing, but the code was working just fine when my web forms were submitting the data. Eventually, after losing 1 hour on logging all sorts of stupid things, I realized that my unit tests were somehow passing the request parameter in a "pure" form -- namely, the object was a `Hash` already, but when my webforms (or manual headless testing via cURL) did sumbit the data, the params were as you expect -- a string representation of a hash.

Using this small code snippet above is, of course, a bandaid, but it delivers.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 3):

Convert hash into JSON using `to_json`

Answer (score 0):

The error is telling you that [ActiveSupport::JSON.decode](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/JSON.html#method-i-decode) expects to be provided with a string, but is unable to coerce the argument you are providing it into a string.  The argument provided to it here is "product_params" which returns a ActionController::Parameters (a loosely wrapped Hash).

If you are using "out of the box" style Backbone there is no need to decode what is being POSTed to that action. Just change the action to:

```
@product = Product.new(product_params)
```

The structure of your product_params method indicates that the action is expecting the data you are POSTing to look like this:

```
{
  product: {
    title: "Foo",
    data: "bar"
  }
}
```

and that your Product model has two attributes that will be populated by .new: title and data.

If you are explicitly encoding something into JSON on the client side you need to figure out what POST parameter it is being submitted as and the decode it on the server (again - there is almost certainly not a good reason to jump through hoops like that).